# What's the stuff before the title sequence in a TV show called?

Tags: production, terminology

A lot of TV shows are structured like:

1. Some common generic opening footage.
2. A few minutes of intro to the episode.
3. Title sequence and credits.
4. The rest of the show.

#1 is a little rarer, sci fi especially seems to have it.

What are #1 and #2 called?

Comment: otherwise it is called a Prologue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is generally referred to as a "[teaser](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheTeaser)" and also referred to as a "[cold-open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_open)" or a "cold opening".

Per TV Tropes;

> Also known as a Cold Opening or "Cold Open." A one to five minute
>   mini-act at the beginning of the show, sometimes before the opening
>   credits, that is used to set up the episode and catch the audience's
>   attention.

Comment: Ah. Does this also include #1?

Comment: @JasonC - Yeah, like a couple of quick flashes of the brand? Yes, that's part of the cold-open. Often the branding will appear as a banner at the bottom as well.